# how to render JavaScript using pug/jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

For example, I pass a `user` variable to this pug file, and I want to run some js code after dom has loaded.

```
 script.
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        console.log(#{user.name});//log the user's name
    });
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Why not have the script in a file which then gets referenced?

Comment: Then I have to make an ajax call to get the `user`, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're trying to use a string interpolation `#{user.name}` outside of a string. Use `!{user.name}` instead for [unescaped code](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped) interpolation. If you need this to be in a string you'll need to surround the variable in quotes as well.

```
console.log('!{user.name}');
```

Comment: Thanks Soviut. But I still can't get it work. Could you please provide a full example based on my code above.

Comment: @JackWang The code you're using is `console.log(!{user.name});` right?

Comment: Soviut is right. I forget to add single quote. Complete code should be: `console.log('!{user.name}');`

Comment: I've added that to the answer.